# What is the inverse function of $x^{x^x}....$ x times?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse-function

Let $M(x) = x^{x^x}...$ x times. How would I extend this function to take on decimals and negatives inputs. I feel like this could be done in a way that makes sense similar to how $x^x$ is easily extended (with decimals like 0.5 being roots and so on). Also, what is $M^{-1}(x)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you mean: $M(x)=x\uparrow\uparrow x$ where $\uparrow\uparrow$ is *Knuth's up-arrow notation*.

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON Based on the way it is written, I interpret his equation as $$M(x)=x\uparrow^xx$$

Comment: Actually $x^x$ isn't that easy. If you think so, try to find it's value for $x = -\pi$. Now, what would **$x$ times** mean if $x$ isn't a natural number?

Comment: Many extensions dont make many sense, by example the extension of the factorial function to the gamma function doesnt make necessarily sense compared with other extensions of the factorial function. Then you can extend this function as you want depending on the characteristics that you want for the function (by example continuity, differentiability, monotonicity, convexity, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

The inverse operations of [tetrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) are noted as the [super-logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm) and the [super-root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Super-root).
$$\large{M=\;^nx=x^{x^{.^{.^x}}}}$$
**Super-Logarithm**

> For all real numbers $n$ and $x\gt 1$, we have
>   $$\large{\operatorname{slog}_x\left(M\right)=\operatorname{slog}_x\left(^nx\right)=n}$$

**Super-Root**

> For each integer $n\gt 2$ and $x\geq 1$, we have
>   $$\large{\sqrt[n]{M}_s=\sqrt[n]{^nx}_s=x}$$

**Square Super-Root**

> For $n=2$ and $x\geq 1$, we have
>   $$\large{\sqrt{M}_s=\sqrt{^2x}_s=x}$$

Hope this helps.